# MediaStore returning NULL

Tags: java, android, mediastore

This should be a lot easier than it has been... but I'm just trying to get the full path for an image from URI.

```
String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME};
```

Will correctly display the name of the file but:

```
String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
```

or...

```
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
```

...will only give me NULL.

Maybe I'm just too tired and not thinking straight (this is a VERY small part of a much larger app) but I can't quite understand how that would be possible if the image is clearly there, the Bitmap is working fine, and the display name works. I'm sure I'm missing something easy... I just can't see it at the moment.

The full code is below:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        Uri selectedImageUri = null;
        if (data != null) {

            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME};

            ContentResolver cr = this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();

            Cursor metaCursor = cr.query(selectedImageUri,
                    projection, null, null, null);
          metaCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);

            if (metaCursor != null) {
                try {
                    if (metaCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        imagepath = metaCursor.getString(0);
                        Log.i(TAG, "UriB: " + metaCursor.getString(0));
                    }
                } finally {
                    metaCursor.close();
                }
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "Uri: " + selectedImageUri.toString());

        }





        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri));
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            messageText.setText("Uploading file path: " + imagepath);
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            messageText.setText("Error");
        }


    }
}
```

androidmanifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jon.bon" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```

I know there are a lot of pages on this because I have about 7 of them open right now, but I just can't get why I'm stuck.

**EDIT**

It looks like I might have to use EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI. But when I do this:

```
Cursor metaCursor = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
```

...I get some completely random (well... actually ONE very specific) path no matter what image I try to work with. Like it isn't related at all.

Comment: Did you handle the android permission?

Comment: @muazhud Yes. For read and write External. (though it's possible I screwed up something else in the Manifest. I've updated my post.

Comment: for which os version are you tryiing

Comment: 6.0. API version 23

Comment: Check Setting >Permissions >If enable or not

Comment: I posted my manifest. External write and read are enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If permission is enable code below will work for  'Intent.ACTION_PICK'.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.PICK_GALLERY);
```

If not then add the Device specification . OnActivity Result as follows .

```
if(responseCode == activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode==Constants.PICK_GALLERY){
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        try {
            Cursor c = activity.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
            c.close();
            if(picturePath==null) {
                picturePath=selectedImage.getPath();
            }
            //Use picturePath for setting bitmap  or to crop 
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: For the intent I'm getting "Can't resolve symbol Constants" error.

Comment: Constants.PICK_GALLERY is a request code .You can use any positive integer instead of it .

Comment: Wow... Of COURSE. I must really be tired! Hahaha! 20 hours straight working on this project... at least two of those just working on this. We have a winner! Many thanks.